# Ignored and deleted files in local Git master, but changes aren't reflected in upstream/master when force pushed

Tags: git, heroku

I'm trying to remove the `app/assets/images` files from the `master` branch on my heroku repo.  I've got that directory in my `.gitignore` file and my local master is up to date with those files deleted.  I did the delete with `git rm -rf app/assets/images` successfully. I've tried `git push heroku master --force` but the app/assets/images directory is still present on the remote repo.  Is there a command to completely replace heroku master with my local master?

To clarify my problem:  I am attempting to push my latest master commit to heroku master.  My slug size is too large.  I want to remove the `app/assets/images` directory so that I may have more room to add to `public/assets`.  After making the change to `.gitignore` and recommitting the code, my slug size is the same.  I am not sure I understand git well enough to answer the questions posed in the comments.

Thanks.

Comment: When you try to force push to heroku and you say that it doesn't work, are there any error messages?

Comment: It "works" but the app/assets/images files are still present.

Comment: When you say the files are "still present" on the remote repo, does that mean that they're still tracked in Git on the remote repo?  Or are they actually being ignored by Git on the remote, but are still physically present on disk?

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, but i am assuming your heroku repo is a remote?

Comment: @Joe, yes it is remote.

Comment: @ColdHawaiian, to the best of my knowledge they are still being stored on the heroku server.

Comment: @JoeEssey what does your `.gitignore` file look like?

Answer (score 3):

Putting the names of files in .gitignore doesn't remove them from the repo.  It just tells git to ignore them, in the future.  If you want to remove the files, just do it as you would normally:

```
git rm -rf app/assets/images
git commit
git push
```

Comment: Right!  As the answer below points out, of course, you need to remove the .gitignore file, while you do the rm.  Then replace it.

Answer (score 0):

to the best of my knowledge - by adding the directory .gitignore you are telling git to not track, push or bother with changes made to it. [which is not what you want to do YET until it is empty]

this being said you are telling your pushes to leave that remote app/assets/images directory alone.

you want to take that line for your [DIR] out of the .gitignore file ( or comment it like such )

*.gitignore*

```
#app/assets/images/
```

then remove the files from images working on your local.

```
     git rm -rf app/assets/images/*
```

make a commit then a push with that commit containing directory empty...

```
    git commmit -m "removed the images from"
    git push [remote] master
```

then you can ignore it once more and it will remain unchanged as long as no other process alters the working directory on the remote